# Mi macro no se ejecuta por completo

Tags: excel, macros

estoy realizando un macro que consiste en eliminar datos duplicados de una columna en excel, (mantener el primer dato e eliminar los datos restantes), el problema esque tengo que ejecutar muchas veces el macro para realizar la tarea por completo, este es mi código, para ver si me pueden orientar.

```
Sub Principal()
    Dim lngFila As Long
    Dim strB As String
    Dim strColumnaB As String
    Dim valor1 As String
    Dim valor2 As String
    Dim contador As Integer

    lngFila = 1
    strB = "B"
    strColumnaB = strB + CStr(lngFila)

    Do
        Range(strColumnaB).Select
        valor1 = Range(strColumnaB).Value

        lngFila = lngFila + 1
        strColumnaB = strB + CStr(lngFila)
        Range(strColumnaB).Select
        valor2 = Range(strColumnaB).Value

        If (valor1 = valor2) Then
            Range(strColumnaB).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Loop Until Range(strColumnaB).Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, por que tu macro lo que hace es recorrer la columna y al eliminar una fila avanza otra, lo cual, cuando tienes más de una repetida te salteará alguna de las repeticiones. Lo que deberías hacer es si una `fila` se repite con `fila + 1`, borrar efectivamente `fila + 1`, pero no avanzar, con esto eliminas todas las repeticiones y recién avanzas cuando `fila` y `fila + 1` son distintas.

Te sugiero también algunos cambios para hacer más compacto el código:

```
Sub DeleteRepeatedSecuentialValues()

    Dim Row As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Row = 1
    While ws.Cells(Row, 2).Value <> ""
        If ws.Cells(Row, 2).Value = ws.Cells(Row + 1, 2).Value Then
            Range("B" & (Row + 1)).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            Row = Row + 1
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

En vez de seleccionar rangos de celda para verificar valores accedemos directamente por índice a cada celda de la columna 2 (B).

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, me has ilustrado y con gusto acepto las sugerencias.